# Maximize browser window for Firefox with Selenium WebDriver C#

Tags: c#, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver

For Chrome I have this code :

```
    List<String> capabilityValue = new List<string>();
    capabilityValue.Add("--start-maximized");
    capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.Chrome();
    capabilities.SetCapability("chrome.switches", capabilityValue);
    capabilities.Platform = new Platform(platform);
    WebDriver driver = new WebDriver ("www.google.com", capabilities);
```

I try to replace `chrome.switches` with `firefox.switches`. For Mozilla Firefox this doesn't work.

Can anyone know how can I open site as maximized?

Comment: I don't understand why some guys gave negative votes to this, the accepted answer has 4+ and the post 2k views already. So the replacement with `firefox.switches` was naive but the question utility remains.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For Firefox use -

```
driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
```

You can check this link for more details - [How do I maximize the browser window in Selenium WebDriver (Selenium 2) using C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3189430/how-do-i-maximize-the-browser-window-using-webdriver-selenium-2)

Comment: Doesn't work for me .I receive an error message : Unexpected error .

Comment: @Cr123 upgrade your webdriver to the latest version.

Comment: This actually works with Chrome too as of now. If you get `Unexpected error` upgrade selenium-webdriver to latest. FYI the javascript syntax for this is `browser.manage().window().maximize();`

Answer (score 0):

Firefox doesn't have a command line parameter to open the window maximized but you could specify the window size explicitly instead. E.g. this should set window size to 800x600:

```
capabilityValue.Add("-width");
capabilityValue.Add("800");
capabilityValue.Add("-height");
capabilityValue.Add("600");
```

Comment: I Try to write so  : 
                    capabilityValue.Add("1024");
                    capabilities.SetCapability("-width", capabilityValue);
                    capabilityValue.Add("768");
                    capabilities.SetCapability("-height", capabilityValue);
                    capabilities.Platform = new Platform(platform); but doesn't work.Can you write me all the code?

Comment: it works If I put driver.Manage().Window.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1152,864).But how to get max width and max height?