# How to Maximize a firefox browser window using Selenium WebDriver with node.js

Tags: firefox, selenium-webdriver

How do we maximize a firefox browser using Selenium WebDriver (Selenium 2) with node.js. I am using `wd` package for Selenium WebDriver to write the tests. I have tried executing `window.resizeTo(1366,768);` usin `eval` or `execute` but didn't work.

I am using Selenium WebDriver 2.25.0

Comment: What version of webdriver are you on?

Comment: I'm using selenium webdriver 2.25.0

Comment: I hope this post will helps you.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3189430/how-do-i-maximize-the-browser-window-using-webdriver-selenium-2

Comment: Irrelevant to node.js, but just for googlers like me: in Python it is done by `driver.maximize_window()`

Answer (score 69):

Have you tried :

```
driver.manage().window().maximize()
```

[**Doc**](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/remote/RemoteWebDriver.RemoteWebDriverOptions.RemoteWindow.html#maximize%28%29)

Comment: I'm using asynchronous style programming with node.js. I've tried to use it after the driver.init() call but it returns "TypeError: Object #<EventEmitter> has no method 'manage'"

Comment: If you're using capybara: `page.driver.browser.manage.window.maximize` (ie access selenium driver via `page.driver.browser`).

Answer (score 9):

First instantiate a firefox driver

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

then maximize it

```
 driver.manage().window().maximize();
```

Answer (score 6):

Use this code:

```
driver.manage().window().maximize()
```

works well,

Please make sure that you give enough time for the window to load before you declare this statement.

If you are finding any element to input some data then provide reasonable delay between this and the input statement.

Answer (score 4):

```
driver.manage().window().maximize();
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this working for Firefox:

```
driver.manage().window.maximize();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Selenium WebdriverJS than the below code should work:

```
var window = new webdriver.WebDriver.Window(driver);
window.maximize();
```

Answer (score 1):

Call `window` as a function.

`driver.manage().window().maximize();`

Answer (score 1):

The statement :: `driver.manage().window.maximize();`  Works perfectly, but the window maximizes only after loading the page on browser, it does not maximizes at the time of initializing the browser.

here : (driver) is called object of Firefox driver, it may be any thing depending on the initializing of Firefox object by you only.

Comment: What workaround do you recommend?
I've checked that it works but not always.

Answer (score 1):

```
driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
self.ff_driver = Firefox()
self.ff_driver.maximize_window()
```

Answer (score 1):

One way, everyone already have written in thier answers:

```
driver.manage().window().maximize()
```

but if you **looking for alternative ways**, here you are:

```
driver.manage().window().setSize(screenResolution);
```

or

```
driver.findElement(By.id("......")).sendKeys(Keys.F11);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.manage().window().maximize() ;
```

works perfectly and at the very beginning it maximizes the window. Does not wait to load any page.

Answer (score 0):

As of **2020**, the correct answer is :

## `driver.maximize_window()`