# How to maximize selenium screen

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Would anyone know how to maximize the selenium webdriver window with java and google chrome.

I already tried some commands like `maximize () window ()` and did not work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Maximize a firefox browser window using Selenium WebDriver with node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14052173/how-to-maximize-a-firefox-browser-window-using-selenium-webdriver-with-node-js)

Comment: What version of ChromeDriver and Selenium are you using?

Comment: JeffC - 
I had already visualized this question but I am not using the node.js I tried the commands described in it and did not work.

Comment: smit9234#
ChromeDriver> 2.25 
selênio> 3.6

Comment: It sounds like ChromeDriver might be out of date (assuming Chrome is able to automatically update).  You should consider using the latest version of ChromeDriver.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this:

```
        String chromeDriver = "/PathTo/chromedriver";
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", chromeDriver);

        ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

        //set your max dimension
        java.awt.Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        Dimension dim= new Dimension((int)screenSize.getWidth(),(int)screenSize.getHeight());

        driver.manage().window().setSize(dim);
```

Comment: even better though  `Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();`  since this would be a "true" maximize instead of an arbitrary width/height

Comment: @sircapsalot You are right, I inserted your improvement.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I did it.

```
    ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
    chromeOptions.addArguments("--start-maximized");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Maximizing Chrome Window.
int x=1280; //according to your screen resolution
int y=860;  //according to your screen resolution
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
executor.executeScript("window.resizeTo(x, y);");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try too sending keystrokes:

```
SendKeys(Keys.ALT, " "); // Space, open window menu    
SendKeys("x"); // Maximize
```

Include a pause between keystrokes, although it could work for you without it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a Mac you'll need to use the following

```
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.addArguments("--start-fullscreen");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the WebDriver API, and this will work with other browsers and RemoteWebDriver:

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.manage().window().maximize();
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/26998387/5603509

Answer (score 0):

Try following code:

```
            ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
            options.addArguments("start-maximized"); //This maximizes the window
            options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", chromePrefs);
            WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```